# Application supports iTunes file sharing not working in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, itunes, file-sharing

I have some strange issue with "Application supports iTunes file sharing" aka "UIFileSharingEnabled".

I have a few applications that need iTunes file sharing support and all of them were actually working on older iOS versions until I upgraded some devices to iOS 10.

I've been trying to find some references about this but no success so far.

The only thing I was able to find is that I should include the "CFBundleDisplayName" and I did, although I am not sure I see the reason behind this. However, no luck.

Here's the info.plist file for one of the apps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string> Photo Library Access Warning</string>
    <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
    <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? All apps work on devices with iOS 9.3 and worked on iOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, I installed Xcode 8.1 and iOS 10.1 and now it works.
It would seem the iTunes version I had installed was not compatible with iOS 10.